# Show $U(f,Q) \leq pM\|Q\| + U(f,P)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is my first question on SE Mathematics, so please let me know if I need to address any formatting or SE related things. Thanks.

Assume that $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a bounded function with $m=\inf_{a\leq x\leq b} f(x)$ and $M=\sup_{a\leq x\leq b} f(x)$. Let $P = \{x_0,\ldots,x_p\}$ and $Q = \{y_0,\ldots,y_q\}$ be partitions of [a,b].

Prove: 
$U(f,Q) \leq pM\|Q\| + U(f,P)$, and $L(f,Q) \geq pm\|Q\| + L(f,P)$.

Am I on the right track with this proof? I think I'm missing a piece at the end of my work to really prove the inequality.

Apply the definitions of upper and lower Riemann sums and replacing the max of the interval, $[x_{k-1},x_k]$, with M:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}M_k(y_k-y_{k-1}) & \leq pM\|Q\| + \sum_{l=1}^{n}M_l(x_l-x_{l-1}),\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n}M_k(y_k-y_{k-1}) & \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}M(y_k-y_{k-1}).  
\end{align}
$$

and the same for $M_l$
$$
\begin{align}
 pM\|Q\| + \sum_{l=1}^{n}M_l(x_l-x_{l-1}) & \leq pM\|Q\| + \sum_{l=1}^{n}M(x_l-x_{l-1}).
\end{align}
$$
Now we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}M(y_k-y_{k-1}) & \leq pM\|Q\| + \sum_{l=1}^{n}M(x_l-x_{l-1}), \\
M\sum_{k=1}^{n}(y_k-y_{k-1}) & \leq pM\|Q\| + M\sum_{l=1}^{n}(x_l-x_{l-1}), \\
M(y_q-y_{0}) & \leq pM\|Q\| + M(x_p-x_{0}), \\
M(b-a) & \leq pM\|Q\| + M(b-a), \\
(b-a) & \leq p\|Q\| + (b-a), \\
0 & \leq p\|Q\|.
\end{align}
$$

The proof for the lower sum is similar, but I am not sure if everything above holds.